# if and or clauses in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i cant understand why this simple function doesnt work in the way i want it to work :)

```
c = document.form.product_catid.selectedIndex;
if (document.form.product_name.value == "" && document.form.product_catid[c].value == "")
{
    alert ("Please, define at least product name or product category !");
    return false;
}
else if (!(document.form.product_name.value == "")) 
{
    return true;
}
else if (!(document.form.product_catid[c].value == "")) 
{
    return true;
}
else
{ 
    alert ("Please, dont define two of them at the same time!");
    return false; 
}
return true;
```

all i want is when input with name product_name is filled OR select with name product_catid is selected, the function is returned true, but if none of them or both are defined, i want it to alert two different alerts ) thank you all for the help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: What is the actual behavior you are seeing? Also, you don't need the final `return true;` as it is not reachable.

Comment: modify your function so that it returns true at the very end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try debugging your case using Chrome Developer Tools, Firebug, or something similar. My suspicion is that you are trying to compare `""` and `undefined` in the `document.form.product_catid[c].value == ""` clause (this will be the case when `selectedIndex` is `-1`). Try just `!document.form.product_catid[c].value` instead.

Comment: you were right :) just changed the first if clause to !document )) both of them, now it works

Comment: this is still not logically correct as the function still exits early (returning `true`) if both of the inputs have been populated

Comment: Why? That's exactly what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Once you use the `return` statement the function "ends":

```
alert ("Please, define at least product name or product category !");
return false; // Exit point
...
...
// this will not be executed.
alert ("Please, dont define two of them at the same time!"); 
return false;
```

---

```
var returnValue = true;

if (document.form.product_name.value == "" && document.form.product_catid[c].value == "")
{
    alert ("Please, define at least product name or product category !");
    returnValue = false;
}
else if (document.form.product_name.value == "") 
{
    return true;
}
else if (document.form.product_catid[c].value == "") 
{
    return true;
}
else
{ 
    alert ("Please, dont define two of them at the same time!");
    returnValue = false; 
}
return returnValue;​
```

Comment: OP didn't mean the two different alerts _for the same input_ but rather one, depending on the input data combination (you cannot have none of the values defined and both of the values defined at the same time.)

Comment: So, if the `(document.form.product_name.value == "" && document.form.product_catid[c].value == "")` check has fired, how can any of the `(!(document.form.product_name.value == ""))` and `(!(document.form.product_catid[c].value == ""))` fire, too? We know they won't, for sure...

Comment: @gdoron nope didnt help, it still returned true if both of them defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var product = document.form.product_name.value;
var category = document.form.product_catid[document.form.product_catid.selectedIndex].value
if (product || category) {
    if (product && category) {
        alert ("Please, dont define two of them at the same time!");
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
else {
    alert ("Please, define at least product name or product category !");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of your conditions are incorrect.

As it stands:

1. Your first check is that both to handle the scenario where both inputs are empty, this works as expected.
2. Your next check is that one of the values isn't empty
3. the next check is that the other value isn't empty
4. then you assume that by this point both inputs aren't empty (your `else` condition)

Consider this: condition 1 ensures that both inputs aren't empty - which means, logically, **at least one of them is non-empty**. Following on from this, given that we now know at least one of them is non-empty, condition 2 or condition 3 **will always evaluate to `true`**. The result of this is that the 4th code path will never execute.

To remedy this, put your check that both inputs are not populated as an explicit condition.:

```
function validateInput() {

    //replace values here to test function
    var productCatId = "",
        productName = "gjghj";

    //uncomment when using real values
    //var productCatId = document.form.product_catid[document.form.product_catid.selectedIndex].value,
    //    productName = document.form.product_name.value;

    //check both aren't empty
    if (productName == "" && productCatId == "")
    {
        alert ("Please, define at least product name or product category !");
        return false;
    }
    //check both aren't populated
    else if (productName != "" && productCatId != "")
    { 
        alert ("Please, dont define two of them at the same time!");
        return false; 
    }
    //by now we know that both aren't empty, and both aren't populated, therefore only one is populated, so return true;
    return true;

}
```